# Getting alert error trying to install opencart plugin

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have encountered a problem. When I try to install additional module or plugin to opencart I keep watching that type of error. When I go to 294 line of code nothing seems to be problematic there, it's a snippet about ftp login, but the alert message want me to remove '<' from some part of code. Do you have any ideas of what should I do with this error because I literally cannot install any of plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Installing quickfix module will help avoiding such errors.

Here is the website to load quickfix module:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/download&extension_id=18892&member_token=DerRKkHUCz4MRCc8cZPDOkKGj5ss8GbC